# Python Scrapy : response object different from source code in browser

Tags: python, scrapy, response

I'm working on a project using Scrapy.

All wanted fields but one get scraped perfectly. The content of the missing field simply doesn't show up in the Scrapy response (as checked in the scrapy shell), while it does show up when i use my browser to visit the page. In the scrapy response, the expected tags are there, but not the text between the tags.

There's no JavaScript involved, but it is a variable that is provided by the server (it's the current number of visits to that particular page). No iframe involved either.

Already set the user agent (in the settings-file) to match my browser.
Already set the download delay (in the settings-file) to 5.

EDIT (addition):

- The page : http://www.fincaraiz.com.co/apartamento-en-venta/bogota/salitre-det-1337688.aspx
- Xpath to the wanted element : //*[@id="numAdvertVisits"]

What could be the cause of this mystery ?

Comment: If you can see it in your browser, but it's not in the response in scrapy, maybe that visit counter is in an iframe?

Comment: No iframe involved either (have updated the question).

Comment: could you provide the url of the page you're trying to scrape ?

Comment: URL and Xpath to element added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an ajax/javascript loaded value.

What steps did you take to determine there is no JS involved?  I loaded the page w/o javascript, and while that area of the page had the stub content ("Visitas"), the actual data was written there with an ajax request.

You can still load that data using scrapy, it'll just take an additional request to the URL endpoint normally accessed via on-page ajax.  The server returns the number of visits in XML, via the script at http://www.fincaraiz.com.co/WebServices/Statistics.asmx/GetAdvertVisits?idAdvert=1337688&idASource=40&idType=1001 (try loading that script and you'll see the # of visits for the page you provided in the original email).

There is another ajax request that returns "True" for that page, but I'm not sure what the data's actual meaning is.  Still, it may be useful:

http://www.fincaraiz.com.co/WebServices/Statistics.asmx/DetailAdvert?idAdvert=1337688&idType=1001&idASource=40&strCookie=13/11/2014:19-05419&idSession=10hx5wsfbqybyxsywezx0n1r&idOrigin=44

Comment: Thanks Travis, excellent answer. I assumed no Javascript was involved because the content wasn't in a script. But AJAX decided otherwise.