# Using Scrapy, when I try to scrape two almost identical pages, the CSS selector works for one but not the other

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, scrapy

The selector is:

`response.css('div.dp-conteudo__esquerda span.varpb').extract_first()`

Pages are [this](https://dicionario.priberam.org/putear) and [that](https://dicionario.priberam.org/puteares).

First one returns the correct *span* normally, but the second one doesn't return anything.

The only relevant difference I can see is that the second page has a *span* with the *varpb* class appear first in a different part of the code, but it's the same as the other one I wanted. In line 581 of second page's source code:

```
...
<a class="--link" href="/putear"><span class="varpt">putear</span><span class="varpb">putear</span></a><span class="mx-2" style="color:#888888;">]</span></item> ou
...
```

Even if it didn't get the "correct" *span*, shouldn't it get this one? Am I missing something?

To make this clear: I don't care about making it work (by other means;changing the selector), I want to understand why it doesn't, please.

If any portuguese-speaking person wonders why I was scraping **these** words, it was for a game of Scrabble.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Alexander's answer and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595209/python-scrapy-response-object-different-from-source-code-in-browser), I realized scrapy isn't scraping the HTML code I expected, but rather an "incomplete" version of it. I can't confirm this since I didn't see this with my own eyes (due to poor understanding of the code; sorry), but apparently this is due to Ajax calls being made by the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first page --> [this](https://dicionario.priberam.org/putear).  You get the result `<span class="varpb">putear</span>` which I believe is what you are expecting to get from the example in your question. This is the only result because it's the only `span`  le

For the second page --> [that](https://dicionario.priberam.org/puteares) you get nothing because there are no `span` elements with a class of `varpb` that are descendants from a `div` element with a class of `dp-conteudo__esquerda`.  Both of those elements with those classes exist but they don't exist in that branch of the element tree.

---

##### Edit

It appears the issue is that you are not looking at the actual source html for the pages you are referring to.

One way to be sure that you are actually looking at the html content that is being parsed by scrapy is to save the `response.text` to an html file locally and actually inspect it yourself.  This ensures that you are seeing the same html that scrapy sees.

Alternatively you can use `view(response)` in scrapy shell if you want to view the html seen by scrapy in your browser.

```
view(response)
```

Here is an example of how you might do that with scrapy shell:

```
In [2]: fetch('https://dicionario.priberam.org/putear')
2023-12-28 00:22:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-12-28 00:22:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://dicionario.priberam.org/putear> (referer: None)

In [3]: with open('putear.html', 'wt', encoding='utf8') as fd:
   ...:     fd.write(response.text)
   ...:

In [4]: fetch('https://dicionario.priberam.org/puteares')
2023-12-28 00:23:09 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://dicionario.priberam.org/puteares> (referer: None)

In [5]: with open('puteares.html', 'wt', encoding='utf8') as fd:
   ...:     fd.write(response.text)
   ...:
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Both pages have a `div` with the `dp-conteudo__esquerda` class, both of them have the `span` with `varpb` class inside said `div`. In the second page's source code, you can find it in line 552. Did I miss anything? Thanks for answering.

Comment: @dumby the branch that starts on line 552 ends at line 714.... nowhere in between those 2 lines is there a span element with `varpb` as a class

Comment: as I stated in the question, there is one in line 581. There are also more spans with the `varpb` class in the following lines: 583, 591, 594, 608, 610, 614 and 620.

Comment: @dumby  No there is not.  You are looking at the wrong html source.  Line 608 only has a single div element.  line 614 is completely empty as is line 620....

Comment: Thank you! I see it now, the html code scrapy gets is different from the one in the actual page. It seems that happens because of an ajax call that apparently loads that code after the point where it is scraped. Which is weird, because other similar pages with conjugations instead of the "correct" word worked just fine. But anyways, thank you! I can't upvote your answer but I'll accept it and edit the question with the new information.

Comment: You can view the html that scrapy see (in the scrapy shell) by 'view(response)' .
It will open the page in browser. Then you can inspect this page in the browser or save it.

I had similar problem that was caused by dynamic loading more items in the page (simply to accelerate the perceived page load time)